# How to filter a list based on another list using Linq?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, linq

I have these two lists, one a list of **Venue** Objects, one a list of **BlockedVenues** objects.

I need to filter each item in the **listOfAllVenues** so that it doesn't contain any venue
 that is blocked

```
     IQueryable<Venue> listOfAllVenues = MyDB.Venues;
     IQueryable<BlockedVenue> listOfBlockedVenues = Mydb.BlockedVenue;
     //I need something to accomplish this please
     // var listOfAllVenues_WithoutBlocked_Venues = 
                           ( Select All venues from listOfAllVenues
                             where listOfAllVenues.ID is NOT in
                             listOfBlockedVenues.VenueID)
```

Please note that yes both list types are different, but **listOfAllVenues** has an int ID field, and **listOfBlockedVenues** has a VenueID int field, i need to use these two

Many Thanks

Comment: So you want everything from `listOfAllVenues` [Except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vstudio/bb300779.aspx) the ones in `listOfBlockedVenues`?

Comment: @Corak yep, but types are different

Comment: @Corak yes exactly :) types are different, true but listOfAllVenues has an int ID field, and listOfBlockedVenues has a VenueID int field, i need to use these two

Comment: Ah, different types (why? o_O), too bad. So @wudzik s answer. ^_^

Comment: Do Venue and BlockedVenue have a common base type?

Answer (score 121, accepted):

Try this:

```
var filtered = listOfAllVenues
                   .Where(x=>!listOfBlockedVenues.Any(y=>y.VenueId == x.Id));
```

It will get all Venues where Id is not in blockedVenues list

Comment: simplified:

`var filtered = listOfAllVenuses.Where(x=>listOfBlockedVenues.All(y=>y.VenueId != x.Id));`

Comment: @RomanY thanks for comment, but I never found "all not equal" simpler than "not any", so I find no simplification here :)

Comment: The specified LINQ expression contains references to queries that are associated with different contexts.

Answer (score 3):

As of NET 6, you can use `ExceptBy`.

```
var filtered = allVenues.ExceptBy(blockedVenues.Select(x => x.VenueID), venue => venue.ID);
```

This will get all venues except those whose ID is in `blockedVenues.Select(x => x.VenueID)`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.exceptby?view=net-6.0