# How to use LINQ to filter values in a column from a list?

Tags: c#, linq, datagridview, bindinglist

I have a dataGridView with a bindingList as a data source. I want to filter the dataGridView to show only rows that have in a given column value from the list. For example, a list has values 1, 2, and 3. Now I want the dataGridView to display only rows which have in the column ID values 1, 2, or 3. How can I achieve this with LINQ?

I only know how to use LINQ to filter with only one value, not list:

```
datasource.Where(s => s.ID == 1 || s.Id == 2 || s.Id == 3).ToList();
```

I know this works, but it won't work if I don't know what values are going to be in the list.

Comment: Did you try to search for existing questions before post this and answer then?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to filter a list based on another list using Linq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18977863/how-to-filter-a-list-based-on-another-list-using-linq)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code in .Where() to check values against the list:

```
datasource.Where(s => list.Contains(s.ID)).ToList();
```